# Does the series converge? and what it is calculate to

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So, a series of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$, but $a_n=2n^{-1}$ if n is even, but $a_n=2^{-n}$ if $n$ is odd. Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n-1}$ converge, and what it's to. So it's only odd numbers because $2n-1.$ And so $a_{2n-1}=2^{-n}$. With a divergence test, I can not see anything, because the limit is 0. So I don't know if it's converge or not. But $2^{-n}$ is a geometric series, so yes it converge. I calculate this to be $a_n$ converges to 1. This is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, $a_{2n-1}=2^{-(2n-1)}$ and not $2^{-n}$. Pay attention to the subscript of $a$, it should agree with what comes up in the exponent of $2$. So you really have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2^{2n-1}}=\frac12+\frac18+\frac1{32}+\frac1{128}+\cdots $$
which you can recognise as a geometric series. In particular the series is equal to
$$\frac12\left(1+\frac14+\left(\frac14\right)^2+\left(\frac14\right)^3+\cdots\right)=\frac12\frac{1}{1-1/4}=\frac23.$$
Whenever you are confused by the summation $\Sigma$ notation, just write it out and see what it represents. This will be very useful in preventing confusion.